# Why is identifying Frege's indirect sense with customary sense problematic?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, analytic-philosophy, frege

In Miller's *Philosophy of Language*, it is explained that the identification of an expression's indirect sense (i.e. its referent in a doubly indirect context) with its customary sense (i.e. its referent in a singly indirect context) is problematic. For if that were the case, assuming that the customary sense of "chiropodist" and of "foot-doctor" are identical,

> (1) John believes that Frank believes that all chiropodists are chiropodists.

should have the same truth-value as

> (2) John believes that Frank believes that all chiropodists are foot-doctors.

yet there are cases where (1) is true but (2) is false.

The case which I think the author had in their mind is where John believes that Frank is unaware of "chiropodist" and "foot-doctors" being synonymous; but if that were the case, the sentences

> (3) Frank believes that all chiropodists are chiropodists.
> (4) Frank believes that all chiropodists are foot-doctors.

could also have different truth values, hence the sense of "chiropodist" and "foot-doctors" are not the same in the first place. This contradicts the assumption laid out at the beginning. Did I misunderstand Miller's argument?

Comment: If John believes that Frank is unaware of the synonymy then, presumably, John *is* aware of it, so how can (3) and (4) have different truth values?

Comment: @Conifold What I meant is that if John's belief in Frank being unaware of the synonymy renders the truth values of (1) and (2) different, then Frank being indeed unaware of the synonymy should render the truth values of (3) and (4) different — hence the sense of "chiropodist" and "foot-doctors" are not the same in the first place.

Comment: John's belief may be mistaken and Frank could, in fact, be aware of the synonymy. The problem is that if we identify the indirect sense with the customary sense for all levels of indirect nesting we can no longer track dependence of truth values on beliefs of all those involved in the nested contexts. In this case, truth values depend on *both* John's and Frank's beliefs, while the indirect sense remains the *same* throughout, according to the proposal that Miller discusses.

Comment: (2) is false only when John's judgement is wrong epistemically about Frank's customary sense about the apparently ought-to-be-same referents, the presumed intersubjectivity fails here like in many other everyday cases. (1) and (3) are always true *normally* speaking assuming rational agents about their beliefs since 'chiropodists are chiropodists' is a *logical* tautology. For (4) you're right it might be false if all chiropodists are *not* foot-doctors in this world which is apparently false given our existing natural language, ergo assuming same as before, (4) is true without inter issue...

Comment: @Conifold I see what you mean, but if it is possible that "Frank believes that all chiropodists are foot-doctors" could be false, does it not follow that "chiropodist" and "foot-doctor" have different sense, contradicting Miller's assumption?

Comment: It does not follow. It simply means that Frank failed to grasp the customary senses of "chiropodist" and "foot-doctor", which Miller apparently assumes to be co-intensional, i.e. the same "in virtue of meanings". In contrast, "evening star" and "morning star", "Mark Twain" and "Samuel Clemens" in 2.2 do have different customary senses, they are only co-referring "in virtue of external facts".